# umbraco tiny mce absolute urls

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco6

i'm having a issue on tiny mce on umbraco 6.

When i add a image or link on tinymce the urls are converted from

> http://domainx.com/images/someimage.png

to

> domainx.com/images/someimage.png

i've added a few configurations to tinyMceConfig.config

```
<config key="relative_urls">false</config>
<config key="convert_urls">false</config>
<config key="remove_script_host">false</config>
```

but now url's are created without the http or https wich results in wrong path and we can't see the images on the tinymce.

Comment: Which (exact) version are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure any hostname on any node?  If so, add the missing part.

Comment: can you clarify please? what you mean about hostname or node?

Comment: right click on the root node of your website and choose "hostname and culture"

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a function of TinyMCE and not Umbraco itself.  I don't have enough "Rep" to comment, otherwise I would ask what version of TinyMCE is installed/running in your version of Umbraco.

However, while it would appear as though you are on the correct path with your configurations, the documentation (http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:FAQ) says you need to simply add "convert_urls = false" to the customConfig section of tinyMceConfig.config (like below), the Umbraco community appears to be reporting it as a bug (http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-374).

```
<customConfig>
    <config key="convert_urls">false</config>
    ...
</customConfig>
```

Have you tried using //www.example.com rather than http://www.example.com as a possible workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do custom configuration settings for TinyMCE in umbraco ([documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/tinymceconfig/)).

I couldn't find a correct documentation for changing settings, which are of the type boolean, to `false`.
After a while and changing some settings I needed, i've found a way to do it! Just leave the value empty in the customConfig-section:

```
<customConfig>
    <config key="convert_urls"></config>
</customConfig>
```

This resulted in being able to enter (almost) anything as a link, without it being converted.